# how to add extra word to each MySQL record

Tags: mysql

**How to add extra word to each MySQL record.**

**Example Table:**

```
|1    | David
|2    | Fin
|3    | Ronny
|4    | Lisa
```

**Required:**

```
|1    | T David
|2    | T Fin
|3    | T Ronny
|4    | T Lisa
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the string literal with [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) it into the column with an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET name = CONCAT('T ', name);
```

If you need to limit this to certain rows, be sure to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET name = CONCAT('T ', name) WHERE <some condition>;
```

Comment: UPDATE yourtable SET firstname = CONCAT('T ', firstname); is this correct.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) string function to concatenate the extra word and the existing value:

```
UPDATE table SET name = CONCAT('T ', name);
```

Per the documentation:

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid
>   that, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
```